# Why is Dialogflow is asking the same follow-up intent twice?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created a very simple Dialogflow project for the first time and I am having a problem with one of my follow-up intents.  It asks the same follow-up question twice.

[image]

enter image description here
[image]

[image]

[image]

I am testing this inside Dialogflow.  Do you have any suggestions I can try?

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question to include screen shots of all the Intents? How are you testing this? If you're testing it with the Dialogflow test tool on the right of the screen, can you include screen shots of the testing and result JSON at each stage of the conversation?

Comment: I apologize for not doing that in the beginning. I have updated the photo.  I am testing this inside Dialogflow.  Thanks – PKonstant 35 mins ago

Comment: Great. Can you also add screen shots of the service.account.balance.check,  service.account.balance.check-no, and  service.account.balance.check-no-no Intents?

Comment: I added the requested screenshots.  Thanks for looking at them.

Comment: I created another intent with follow ups that mimicked my previous one but using different words and it works fine.  Then I recreated the original again and it asks the same question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue boils down to how Followup Intents work under the covers and the mechanism that Dialogflow uses to enforce them.

They work because the Base Intent will set an Output Context, and the valid Followup Intents are only triggered for the same Input Context. So the `check` intent sets a `check-followup` context, and the `check-no` intent depends on the `check-followup` intent being set. Similarly, the `check-no` intent sets the `check-no-followup` context and `check-no-no` intent expects the `check-no-followup` context to be set.

However, the lifespan of these Contexts are set to 2 initially, and this is decremented each time an Intent is handled. So after the `check-no` intent is processed, we will have two contexts that have been set: `check-followup` *and* `check-no-followup`.

This becomes a dilemma when the user says "no" again. That matches two Intents, and both of those Intents have a Context that is valid at that time: `check-no` (because the `check-followup` context is still active) and `check-no-no` (because the `check-no-followup` context has just been made active). Since more than one Intent could be valid - it is indeterminate which one would be called. This is why it would work for other test cases you had been trying.

In your case, a reasonable solution would be to make sure which context of these two you expect to be valid at that point. In this case, it would make sense that you turn off a Context after the Intent that you expect to match them does. So this means that if the `check-no` context is triggered, then you would set `check-followup` as an output context with one important distinction - **you should explicitly set the lifespan of it to 0**. This would remove that context, so there is no confusion about which Intents are available to handle the user's next reply.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Based on what you said, I changed the "accountbalancecheck-no-followup" lifespan to 1  (it was set to 2) and that worked!. I don't fully understand the lifespan thing.  I thought Contexts are just parameters - input / output.  (I will read up on these.) So basically, the Contexts can determine which intents get called?

Comment: Contexts are the most powerful feature of Dialogflow - definitely should learn about them. Glad this helped!